# SAS: Proc Report span columns instead of rows

Tags: sas, report

Take the following data as an example:

```
data test;
    length IID_p    PREF_p  DATE_p  IID IID_c   PREF_c  DATE_c $12;
    input IID_p $ PREF_p $ DATE_p $ IID $ IID_c $ PREF_c $ DATE_c;
    datalines;
    ABC SHARE   20161024    ABC ABC NOSHARE 20161031
    DEF SHARE   20161024    DEF DEF NOSHARE 20161031
    HIJ NOSHARE 20161024    HIJ Notfound    Notfound    Notfound
    XYZ NOSHARE 20161024    XYZ Notfound    Notfound    Notfound
    ;
run;
```

After a merge, I have the data above and show that `HIJ` and `XYZ` are not in the current week's data with the value `Notfound`.

In the following `PROC REPORT` statement (watered down for brevity), is it possible to span `Not found` across all three columns in the "Current Week" columns?

```
proc report data = merged spanrows nowd;
    column ("Previous week"(IID_p PREF_p DATE_p)) ("Current week"(IID_c PREF_c DATE_c));
run;
```

So instead of the output below, "Not found" would span across all three columns and not be in each individual column:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to merged cells in excel? If so it doesn't seem to be possible in proc report (See: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Merging-Cells-horizontally-in-PROC-REPORT/td-p/79385)
The suggestion here is to annotate your report to cover your desired data cells.

Comment: I don't *think* it's possible, but I think if it is possible it would be through a CSS template (as this sort of thing is probably possible via CSS).  Look at Kevin Smith's papers on CSS templates (and also look if it's truly possible in CSS).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, guys.

Comment: Post to communities.sas.com under ODS. Cynthia Zender from SAS may know, if anyone does.

Answer (score 0):

You can only span rows and columns in the header but not the values/data.